# How to set custom header for all requests that go through OmniAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

This is mostly a thought exercise that I couldn't figure out how to solve. :)

Does anyone know how to set a custom request header for all requests that use the `omniauth` or `omniauth-oauth2` gems?

I've tried something like the following, but I don't see the header in my developer tools in Chrome, for example.

```
OmniAuth.config.before_request_phase do |env|
  env['MY_CUSTOM_HEADER'] = 'true'
end
```

What am I doing wrong here? What am I missing here?

---

Edit based on responses:

Why I need the custom header set doesn't really matter here -- as I mentioned at the top of the question: this is just a curiosity I had. The constraint is that I'd like to test the custom header on any OS or browser, so it's not sufficient to just play with developer tools in Chrome here as not all browsers have that capability on across all OSes.

What I'm trying to do is add a custom header to all outgoing OAuth requests coming out the gem. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An OAuth request handler cannot force a browser (or any similar user-agent) to disclose more information than specified in the HTTP protocol.  Be glad of that: any other posture could lead to information leakage.

The only connection that Omniauth might make itself is that exchanging a code for an access/refresh token.  That is specific to the strategy in question, but strategies have the opportunity to include arbitrary headers in their internal client.  If you're writing a custom strategy that required a basic authentication header during the access token exchange, it might look like this:

```rb
require 'omniauth-oauth2'

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class DemoStrategy < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
      option :name, "demo"
      option :client_options, {
        site: 'https://api.example.org',
        authorize_url: 'https://auth.example.org/oauth2/authorize',
        token_url: 'https://auth.example.org/oauth2/token'
      }

      uid { raw_info['id'].to_s }

      info do
        { email: raw_info['email'], image: raw_info['avatar_url'] }
      end

      extra do
        { raw_info: raw_info }
      end

      def raw_info
        @raw_info ||= access_token.get('user').parsed
      end

      def build_access_token
        options.token_params.merge!(headers: {
          'Authorization' => special_auth_header
        })
        super
      end

      def basic_auth_header
        "Basic " + Base64.strict_encode64("#{options[:demo_id]}:#{options[:demo_secret]}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here, `build_access_token` is overriding the superclass's standard constructor for the internal HTTP client, and injecting extra headers before handing it back up the stack.  Internally that's handed off to the `oauth2` gem, which in turn uses Faraday, so it's likely anything Faraday accepts is a valid option.

If you need additional information carried to the authentication server, it may be encoded in the redirect URL by the strategy.  For example, the omniauth-google-oauth2 strategy is configurable to carry authentication scopes and email hints in the URL that lands on Google's authentication endpoint.

It is also common to include a XSRF state parameter, in conjunction with an encrypted session cookie, to protect against identity spoofing.  Depending on the co-operation of the authentication server, some or all of this data may be reflected in the redirection back to your handler.

At it simplest, that is handled by the `authorize_params` method in the strategy subclass e.g.

```rb
def authorize_params
  super.tap do |params|
    params[:something] = 'my_extra_value'
  end
end
```

However, the volume of code involved in setting up extended parameters may be quite substantial in practice.  For a worked example of doing this with Omniauth I'd suggest taking a looking at the [source code of the Google strategy](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/google_oauth2.rb), and again I'll draw your attention to the `authorize_params` method which is the entry point for this heavy lifting.

In the overall flow of things, those are the touch points where server-side code can actually influence matters.  There's a fundamental expectation that the user's client/browser is participating by executing nothing but normal HTTPS request.

Answer (score 0):

In browser developer tools you can only see request headers that are sent by or response headers received by the browser. Any request headers set by load balancers, reverse proxies, middleware and so on - are only visible to next stage in request handling chain.

OmniAuth lives in middleware, so technically any request in your app uses it, unless some other middleware terminates request chain and renders some response.
Also "request" in omniauth terms is not http request, it's an auth phase, usually happens on `/auth/:provider` (also there're "options" and "callback" phases).

It's not clear why you need setting a request header in a middleware on a request that goes into your own application - when request is going to be handled by omniauth it will not hit your controllers, except for `callback` phase where `request.env['omniauth.auth']` is going to be set.

Since you're mentioned developer tools - probably you want response headers on request phase, to set these you need to override rack response returned from `request_phase` in your strategy. But for oauth2 there's only a redirect (still possible to set headers, but even less sense).

So first you need to be exact on which headers you want to be set at which request/response, there're several of those. Simplified sequence:
[image: diagram]

Comment: thanks for your response! To answer your question about why I'm doing this -- it's just a thought experiment...a wondering if you will that I had one day that I couldn't figure out to solve: I want to add a custom header to the "get auth/provider" phase.

As for your suggestion, I understand how to do that conceptually, but it's still not clear to me how to actually achieve that. Know of any examples that I can use?